# C#: утечка памяти в System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#

есть C# приложение, которое представляет из себя постоянно открытое окно браузера(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) со страницей онлайн-консультанта. Висит всегда в трее и разворачивается когда есть вопрос... События отлавливается по JS...

функционал скриптов простейший:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = er_counter.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (er_counter > 10) { er_counter = 0; showWindow(); webBrowser1.Refresh(); return; }
            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("timestamp").InnerText.Equals(last_date))
            {
                er_counter++;
            } else {
                er_counter = 0;
            }
            last_date = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("timestamp").InnerText;
            object[] codeString2 = { "$('#webim_userbar>li>a').text().trim();" };
            string agent_name = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", codeString2).ToString();

            String title = "[" + last_date + "] [" + agent_name + "] Онлайн-консультант";
            this.Text = title.ToString();
            notifyIcon1.Text = title.ToString();
            object[] codeString = { "webim.isActive;" };
            string t = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", codeString).ToString();
            if( t.Equals("True"))
            {
                showWindow();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            er_counter++;
        }
    }
```

через JS получается текущее имя агента и состояние чата (показать окно, либо ничего нового). Через JS еще в браузере проигрывается музыка по новому событию, но думаю утчека не здесь.

er_counter счетчик ошибок, если вдруг окно подвисло, либо упал инет, старница сама обновится и агент снова на связи.

по началу все норм, память в районе 30Мб... но после 5-6 часов работы выозрастает до 300мб, и далее растет и растет... бывало и по 1.5-2гб.

проблема очевидно в стандартном браузере, подскажите можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Почему бы не создавать `WebBrowser` когда надо развернуть его? И да, проще снять дамп с 300мб+ процесса и посмотреть, что там место занимает.

Comment: @Monk да скорее всего незачем -- это известная проблема, в компоненте есть утечки.

Comment: @Monk причем пересоздание не поможет -- пишут, что там в unmanaged памяти течет.

Answer (score 1):

Перво-наперво, конечно, надо посмотреть профайлером, где течет. И только потом можно решать эту проблему.

Но вообще утечки в `WebBrowser` -- это известная проблема. Лечиться можно либо магией ([раз](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/368755dd-0047-4a88-9951-ba0539266410/wpf-webbrowser-is-not-disposed-properly?forum=wpf), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302933/how-to-get-around-the-memory-leak-in-the-net-webbrowser-control)), либо перезапуском приложения (запустили новую копию себя, потом убились), либо запуском внутри себя отдельного дочернего процесса, который периодически перезапускается.